# How to set the boundaries for UIPopover with a CGRect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I am displaying a popover to be presented in a view but leaving some space at the top.

I am using `presentPopoverFromrect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:` but apart from passing the view I also want to restrict the popover within the view within a rectangle.

which means , the popover should not go outside this rect in the view and also adjust arrows accordingly.
Is there a way that this can be made possible ?

Comment: set content size for popover

Comment: No. What I want is, the popover to not to go outside a Rect in the view it has been added

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite contentSizeForPopover and make it return the values you need.

```
- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopover
{
    return CGSizeMake(180, 360);
}
```

Comment: No. What I want is, the popover to not to go outside a Rect in the view it has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Make the xib size freeform and remove the status bar first .then what ever value set for the view in xib make it the viewdidload as

```
[self setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(widthsetinxib, heightsetinxib)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the 'popoverLayoutMargins' property of UIPopover.
Like so -

```
[myPopoverController setPopoverLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)];
```

This restricts the popover to the specified insets. For details read the documentation of the same method.

P.S. I know this is a very late answer for the question, but I just faced and solved the same issue, so I can vouch for this solution.

Comment: Can you provide link of documentation?